# Relation $R$: $R\circ R \subseteq R \implies R$ is transitive

Tags: functions, relations, equivalence-relations, function-and-relation-composition

Let $R$ be a relation on $X$, a set. If $R\circ R\subseteq R$, then is $R$ transitive?

Answer (score 1):

Just apply the definitions. (This advice applies to most elementary problems of this general type.) In order to show that $R$ is transitive, you must show that if $x,y,z\in X$ and $\langle x,y\rangle,\langle y,z\rangle\in R$, then $\langle x,z\rangle\in R$. Since you know that $R\circ R\subseteq R$, you know that it would be enough to show that $\langle x,z\rangle\in R\circ R$: that would ensure that $\langle x,z\rangle\in R$ and hence that $R$ is transitive.

Now just use the definition of $R\circ R$ to show that if $\langle x,y\rangle,\langle y,z\rangle\in R$, then $\langle x,z\rangle$ **is** in $R\circ R$.

**Added:** The composition $R\circ R$ is the relation on $X$ defined as follows:

$$R\circ R=\left\{\langle x,y\rangle\in X\times X:\exists z\in X\Big(\langle x,z\rangle\in R\text{ and }\langle z,y\rangle\in R\Big)\right\}\;.$$

Informally, you can think of $R$ as a list of the ‘steps’ you can take in $X$: $\langle x,y\rangle\in R$ means that it’s possible to step from $x$ to $y$. In these informal terms, $\langle x,y\rangle\in R\circ R$ means that you can get from $x$ to $y$ in **two** steps: there’s at least one intermediate ‘stepping-stone’ $z$ in $X$ such that you can step from $x$ to $z$ and then from $z$ to $y$.

Comment: Could you, if you had to, explain exactly what an elementary problem of a general type is?

Comment: What is the definition of $R\circ R$.

Comment: @Trancot: Precisely? No. However, just about any of the problems in elementary set theory that you’re likely to encounter will qualify. And understanding the definitions is a prerequisite no matter how complicated or advanced a problem is; it’s just that many of the elementary problems are **nothing more** than application of the definitions, with no ingenuity required.

Comment: @Trancot: Do you not have a definition of the composition of relations in your text or notes? If not, I can certainly give one, but I’d be very much surprised.

Comment: No. Our class just had a midterm, and most people didn't get it.

Comment: @Trancot: Okay; I’ve added a definition of $R\circ R$. This is a special case of the more general notion of composition of relations, $R\circ S$, but there are two ways to define the general composition, and I don’t know which you’re supposed to be using, so I’ve given neither. In this problem $R=S$, and the two definitions coincide, so I don’t have to worry about the problem.

Comment: "An elementary problem of general type" is typically one posed almost immediately after introducing a definition :) I suppose you have either just defined composition of relations or transitivity